# Want to align the text from the rightside..(UITextALignmentRight)

Tags: objective-c, keyboard, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate, inputview

I created a keyboard using on `UITextView`'s `inputView`.

I want to align the text from the `UItextAlignmentRight` but it's not working as it is not calling the `UITextViewDelegate` method when using `inputView`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful to people who are experiencing problems with setting of textAlignment for UITextView. I experimented with different Unicode directional characters and found that:

1. When you set textAlignment property of textView to UITextAlignmentRight, right to left adjustment works correctly if you start your text with a strong left to right character. For example:

   ```
   self.textView.text = [@"\u200e\u202b" stringByAppendingString: yourRtLstring];
   ```
2. If you don't set the textAlignment property of textView (or set to default UITextAlignmentLeft), right to left adjustment works correctly for strong RtL characters.

Answer (score 0):

1. CHeck if your ViewController is implementing the UITextViewDelegate protocol
2. Set the UITextAlignment property on the UITextView to UITextAlignmentRight
3. Which method of UITextViewDelegate are you using?